# Load pre-trained model on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-ec2

I had built a Machine Learning model on my PC, now I want to load this pre-trained model on AWS.
I had seen sagemaker and amazon s3 services but these concepts include data storage and Model building. In my case, I already had a trained model

Answer (score 2):

For your pretrained model, you can upload the model artifact that is generated after training to an S3 location and then use the model artifact with a model container to deploy an inference endpoint on Sagemaker.

You may refer this blog
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/bring-your-own-pre-trained-mxnet-or-tensorflow-models-into-amazon-sagemaker/
It demonstrates how you can bring your own pretrained models into SageMaker